# SELF HELP EVICTION OF ADVERSE POSSESSOR

Tags: florida, eviction

Can I Forcibly remove an adverse possessor without Notice or and Opportunity to be heard, before time bared by the statute of limitation in Florida.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to provide a lot more detail please.  You should also reword the question to be a general question of law rather than a request for specific legal advice (which is off-topic).

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely not. You have to use the legal system, whereby the sheriff is the one who uses force if it is necessary and ordered by the court. You can file an action at your local courthouse. If you want to do this self-help style, figure out how to file a petition, and figure out what you are petitioning the court to do. First off, of course, you need to figure out what you really want. For example, do you want a squatter to leave your apparently abandoned house; do you want a fence removed from your property; or do you just want to be sure that he can't claim possession of a chunk of your land in 3 more years (but the fence doesn't bother you)?

Since you're apparently talking about removing a person from your property, you might start by calling the police. If this is a former tenant as opposed to a stranger who broke in, don't bother (police don't get into civil matters until the court tells them to), just start the appropriate legal process. You might be filing an unlawful detainer action, but it would be a slower eviction if the person is a tenant.

Comment: If he knows about it and objects it can't be adverse possession.